# Math average with php

Tags: php, math, average

Time to test your math skills...

I'm using php to find the average of $num1, $num2, $num3 and so on; upto an unset amount of numbers.  It then saves that average to a database.

Next time the php script is called a new number is added to the mix.

Is there a math (most likely algebra) equation that I can use to find the average of the original numbers with the new number included. Or do I need to save the original numbers in the database so I can query them and re-calculate the entire bunch of numbers together?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If what you mean by average is the 'mean' and you don't want to store all numbers then store their count:

```
$last_average = 100;
$total_numbers = 10;
$new_number = 54;

$new_average = (($last_average * $total_numbers) + $new_number) / ($total_numbers + 1);
```

Comment: `$total_numbers` may not be available.

Comment: $total_numbers is a **required** implementation detail for the specified problem. Either implement it or the problem is unsolvable.

Comment: This will lead to an ever-increasing loss of accuracy. Use $last_total instead of $last_average. See Mike's answer.

Comment: Ah, true, didn't think about that. It's best to keep the $last_sum as well then.

Answer (score 77):

```
array_sum($values) / count($values)
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of this haha

Comment: Division by zero when $values is empty

Comment: $avg = 0;
if(count($values)){
   $avg = array_sum($values) / count($values);
}

Answer (score 13):

```
Average = Sum / Number of values
```

Just store all 3 values, there's no need for anything complicated.

If you store the `Average` and `Sum` then calculate `Number of values` you'll lose a little accuracy due to truncation of Average.

If you store the `Average` and `Number of values` then calculate `Sum` you'll lose even more accuracy. You have more margin for error in calculating a correct value for `Number of values` than `Sum` thanks to it being an integer.

Comment: You don't need to store the average, you can compute it without any loss of precision.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
function avrg()
{
 $count = func_num_args();
 $args = func_get_args();
 return (array_sum($args) / $count);
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php#101727

Answer (score 4):

Thought that I should share my function

```
function avg(array $values) {
    $sum = array_sum($values);
    $count = count($values);
    return ($count !== 0)? $sum / $count: NAN;
}
echo avg([1, 2, 3, 4]); // 2.5
```

Will return the average and also take into account 0, for example dividing by zero always returns NaN (Not a number)

1/0 = NaN
0/0 = NaN

Answer (score 1):

If you know the amount of numbers you can calculate the old sum, add the new one and divide by the old amount plus one.

```
$oldsum = $average * $amount;
$newaverage = ($oldsum + $newnum) / ($amount + 1);
```

Comment: @slebetman - But that's the same as the answer you've accepted.

Comment: Ah.. sorry, I misread the code. I retract my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Typically what you might do is save two pieces of information:

- the sum of all the numbers
- the count of numbers

Whenever you want to get the average, divide the sum by the count (taking care for the case of count == 0, of course). Whenever you want to include a new number, add the new number to the sum and increment the count by 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a 'running average' or '[moving average](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MovingAverage.html)'.

If the database stores the average **and** the number of values averaged, it will be possible to calculate a new running average for each new value.

Answer (score 0):

```
function avgvals($avg_vals,$avg_delimiter=',') { 
 if ( (is_string($avg_vals) && strlen($avg_vals) > 2) && (is_string($avg_delimiter) && !empty($avg_delimiter)) ) { 
    $average_vals = explode($avg_delimiter, $avg_vals); 
        $return_vals = ( array_sum($average_vals) / count($average_vals) ); 
 } elseif ( (is_string($avg_vals) && strlen($avg_vals) <= 2) && (is_string($avg_delimiter) && !empty($avg_delimiter)) ) { 
        $return_vals = $avg_vals; 
 } else { 
        $return_vals = FALSE; 
 } 
   return $return_vals; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
function avg($list){
    $sum = array_sum($list);
    $count = count($list);
  return ($count)? $sum / $count: NAN;
}
print ("Average: ".avg([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Output:

```
Average: 3
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to save all the original numbers in the database.